# Why do I get segmentation fault (semaphore in C)?

Tags: c, get, segmentation-fault, semaphore

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SEM_KEY_FILE ("idSem.txt")

//sem_open
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

int sem_fd;
key_t sem_key;
int sem_id;
sem_fd = open(SEM_KEY_FILE, O_RDWR);
if (sem_fd < 0) {
    perror("Nepodarilo sa otvorit kluc pre citanie");
    return 1;
}
if (read(sem_fd, &sem_key, sizeof(key_t)) != sizeof(key_t)) {
    perror("Chyba pri citani kluca semafora");
    return 2;
}
close(sem_fd);
sem_id = semget((key_t)sem_key, 0, 0666);
printf("%d\n", sem_id);
if (sem_id < 0)
{
    perror("Sada s takymto klucom neexistuje");
    return 3;
}
printf("%d\n", (int) sem_key);
return 0;
}
```

I create and init semaphore in other c file sem_create. There a sem_key is written to idSem.txt In this file sem_open I want to get sem_key from text file and check if semaphore exist, but I only get segmentation fault because sem_id is -1. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


union semun{
int val;
struct semid_ds *buf;
unsigned short *array;
struct seminfo *__buf;
};

//sem_create
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

int hodnota = atoi(argv[1]);
int id;
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
int kluc;

union semun sem_union;
sem_union.val = hodnota;

do{
kluc = rand() % 100000;
id = semget((key_t)kluc, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
}while (id == -1);

if (semctl(id, 0, SETVAL, sem_union) == -1)
    {
    perror("Neuspesne nastavenie hodnoty");
    exit(1);
    return 1;
    }
printf("%d\n", id);
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Is there code that shows how the semaphore key is written to the file?

Comment: I made a script in bash. 

    #!/bin/bash
    semafor=$(sem_get 1) 
    echo $semafor > idSem.txt

Comment: So then if you cat the file you just see a number?

Comment: For example now I enter cat idSem.txt and I get 491522.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file is just plain ascii text, this line will need some extra code:

```
if (read(sem_fd, &sem_key, sizeof(key_t)) != sizeof(key_t)) {
```

Something like:

```
char asciiSemKey[20];
if (read(sem_fd, asciiSemKey, sizeof(asciiSemKey)) < 1)) {
  /* Do your error stuff here. */
}
...
sem_key = atol(asciiSemKey);
```

Comment: I want to open semaphore like this semaphore=${sem_open} Am I doing it right? Because same result segmentation fault.